# float to short conversion error in mikroC

Tags: c, pic, mikroc

I wrote a code in mikroc where pwm signal is applied to motor. 
Now since dutycycle passed to PWM inbuilt function needs to be short datatype and my pid output is of float type i casted float to short.But the problem is that for values less than or equal to hundred casting is done properly whereas for values beyond 100 it gives values such as 65535.
**For eg:
if float value is 255 then short is equal to 65535
 and
if float value is 100 then short is equal to 100
i am not able to figure out what is the mistake?**

Below is my code only  main and UART function

main function

```
  void main() {
  UART1_Init(9600);
  pro=5,i=0,der=0;
  setPoint=100,sel=1;
  actualOut=80;
  pOut=0,iOut=0,dOut=0;
  out=16;
  error=0,lastError=0;
  OPTION_REG=0;
  T1CON=0;
  INTCON=0;
  ADCON0=0;
  CMCON = 0x07;
  TRISC.RC0=1;
  TRISC.RC2=0;
  TRISC.RC6=0;
  PORTC=0;
  while(1){
  out = pid(actualOut);
  duty=(short)out;              out is float type and duty is short
  Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(duty);
  UART1_Write(13); // newline
  pwm(duty);
  actualOut = feedback();

  }
  }
```

UART function

```
 Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(unsigned i) {
 char puf[6]; //for max 5 digits and the end-sign
 WordToStr(i, puf); // in "Conversions" library
 UART1_Write_Text(puf);
 return i;
  }
```

used virtual terminal and uart to display values in proteus
Please help me

Comment: can you indent your code please?

Comment: Are you sure `out` is of type `float` ? What you describe is exactly as if it was `char`.

Comment: i found the solution type casting needs to be done in the following manner                                               unsigned short duty=(unsigned short)out;

Comment: @dcmotor yes, that is indeed the solution, IF `out` is of type `char`, not `float`.

Comment: Out is of type float and works perfect

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution type casting needs to be done in the following manner

```
unsigned short duty=(unsigned short)out;
```

–  dcmotor